# How to combine two graphs created by autoplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

Let's consider two financial assets  (apple and gold) :

```
start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
getSymbols("GOLD", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
```

Let's see how the plots of apple and gold look like :

```
autoplot(Cl(AAPL))
```

[image]

```
autoplot(Cl(GOLD))
```

[image]

However I don't know how can I have them both on one graph. I was trying to search for a solution but none of them is using `autoplot()` function. Is this feasible to have two of the above graphs on one coordinate system ?

I'm looking for something like this but created with `autoplot()`

```
ggplot()+geom_line(aes(x = 1:945, y = Cl(AAPL)))+geom_line(aes(x = 1:945, y = Cl(GOLD)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using e.g. `patchwork` this could be achieved like so:

```r
start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
library(quantmod)

library(ggplot2)
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)

#> [1] "AAPL"
getSymbols("GOLD", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
#> [1] "GOLD"

library(patchwork)

p1 <- autoplot(Cl(AAPL))
p2 <- autoplot(Cl(GOLD))
p1 + p2
```

[image]

**EDIT** Following the example in docs of `zoo::autopilot.zoo` you could make your plot manually using `ggplot2` like so:

```r
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(data = fortify(Cl(AAPL), melt = TRUE), aes(color = "AAPL")) + 
  geom_line(data = fortify(Cl(GOLD), melt = TRUE), aes(color = "GOLD")) + 
  xlab("Index") + ylab("x")
```

[image]

Comment: It's a very good solution, but I would prefer to have these plots on one graph, rather than side by side plots. Do you think this is feasible ? ;))

Comment: I edited my question what exactly I'm looking for

Comment: Hi John. See my edit on how to achieve that. Best S

Comment: Perfect! Just maybe one minor thing. As you can see in legend we have variables mentioned under the word 'colour'. Is there any possbility how can we omit this writing ? i.e. how to delete 'colour' placed in the right side of the graph.

Comment: (: `+ labs(color = NULL)` will remove the title for the color legend. BTW: via labs you can also add a title or change the axes labels.

Answer (score 0):

Create a combined xts/zoo object using `cbind` and then `autoplot` it.  Omit `facet=NULL` if you prefer to have each in its own panel.  Use `scale(closes)` in place of `closes` if you want to normalize the prices first.  The output from the `autoplot` line is shown at the endn.

```
closes <- cbind(Cl(AAPL), Cl(GOLD)) 
autoplot(closes, facet = NULL)
```

### Many stocks

If there are many stocks and we don't want to `cbind` them individually then we could use this code to create `closes` instead.

```
tickers <- c("AAPL", "GOLD")
getSymbols(tickers, from = start, to = end, env = stocks <- new.env())
closes <- do.call("cbind", eapply(stocks, Cl))
```

or we could use this code assuming `tickers` from above:

```
getSymbols(tickers, from = start, to = end)
closes <- do.call("cbind", lapply(mget(tickers), Cl))
```

### Output

[image: screenshot]